# Obtaining the nth-smallest number according to a custom ordering?

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to solve this problem:
http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/102/10232.html

1. Basically, a number `x` is greater than `y`, if the number of `1`'s in binary representation of `x` is greater than `y`;
2. If they do have same number of `1`'s, then we compare in the natural way;

So, now we have a Bitwise sequence composed by integers `1 .. 2147483647`.  Given the index of some integer, how can we get that integer EFFICIENTLY ?

NOTE: the first several integers in the sequence should be:

```
0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, .. 1073741824, 3, 5, 6, 9, ..
-  ---------------------------------  --------------
0           one 1's                       two 1's
```

NOTES:

1. Creating a lookup table would work, but it's just too slow, and too much memory!
2. Distributing all integers into bags with different numbers of 1's is also very slow: how to count in the same bag, do I have to count one by one?
3. I am NOT a student.  I'm a working professional.  Solving ACM problems is just my hobby. Using brute-force is usually NOT my taste, if I believe there is a better efficient algorithm to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can break this down into two separate problems:

1. Finding how many numbers there are with exactly k bits set, and
2. Finding the nth smallest number with exactly k bits set.

Let's suppose you can solve problems (1) and (2).  Then here's a solution to the overall problem, written in Awful Pseudocode:

```
function nthNumber(n):
    let numBitsNeeded = 0;
    while true:
       let x = number of numbers with exactly numBitsNeeded bits.
       if x >= n, break

       n -= x

    return the nth-smallest value with exactly numBitsNeeded bits
```

The idea is to figure out how many bits will be in the number n, and from there to determine which number with that many bits you'll need.

Let's attack each problem separately.

## Part 1: Counting the number of values with exactly k bits set

Fortunately, this part has a nice closed-form solution.  If you have a 32-bit number and want to know how many numbers have exactly k bits set, you can compute the value 32 choose k, since you're selecting which positions in the number will have the bit set.  This can be computed as

> 32! / (k! (32 - k)!)

You can precompute this and put it in a table if you'd like, meaning that you can compute this value in O(1) time.

## Part 2: Determining the nth smallest number with exactly k bits set.

Since all these numbers have the same number of bits and they're compared as usual, you can think of this part of the problem as finding the nth lexicographically ordered combination of k bits.  One way that you could do this is the following: suppose that you knew how many numbers there were with the highest bit at position k, k + 1, k + 2, k + 3, etc.  You could then binary search over those numbers to determine where the highest best of the number would go.  Once you've done that, you can then recursively apply the same procedure but with k - 1 bits to recover the remaining bits of the number.

So now we need to figure out how to count the number of ways to choose k bits with the highest 1 bit at some position p.  Fortunately, that's not that hard either.  If you have k bits and the highest is at position p, then you need to distribute the remaining k - 1 bits in positions less than p.  The number of ways to do this is given by (p - 1) choose (k - 1), which is

> (p - 1)! / (k - 1)!((p - 1) - (k - 1))!

Combining this with the above logic gives you a way to determine where all the bits of the numbers should go without having to count all the way up.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmmm, the 2nd part sounds a little bit complicated, but I will try it.  BTW, it's `31`, NOT `32`. To speed up, I'm also gonna precompute part of the 2nd part in a lookup table, since there are only 31*31 cases.

Comment: @PeterLee templatetypedef already explains it pretty well, but a visual might help. You can think of it as a "bucketing" algorithm where you split the initial set of numbers into buckets. Then you find the bucket your number is in... and split that bucket into even smaller buckets. You keep doing this until the buckets are size 0 or 1 at which point... you have your target number.

Comment: @roliu, Yes, that's what I meant in my comment. Thx :-)

Answer (score 1):

According to @templatetypedef 's core algorithm, I finally got it Accepted:

```
#       Problem     Verdict     Language    Run Time    Submission Date
12534054    10232   Bit-wise Sequence   Accepted    C++     0.018   2013-10-21 00:39:12
```

The credit should still go to @templatetypedef, but I'm also posting the main code for others' reference.

**The code is actually short, because most is my comments :-)**

The main code (I spent a lot of time solving the "Offset 1" issue):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>
#define N 32
using namespace std;

unsigned C[N][N]; // C[k][n] means choose k objects from n objects
unsigned S[N];
void CreateLookupTable()
{
    // Create the C(k, n)
    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
        C[0][n] = 1;
    for (int n = 1; n < N; ++n)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k < n; ++k)
            C[k][n] = C[k][n-1] + C[k-1][n-1];
        C[n][n] = 1;
    }

    // Construct an accumulated sequence from C[i, 31], where i is [0..31]
    int n = N-1;
    S[0] = C[0][n];
    for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        S[i] = S[i-1]+C[i][n];
}

// n: the position in the current bucket
// b: how many 1's in the target number
// h: the index of the possible highest 1
inline void FillBitset(int n, int b, int h, bitset<N>& bs)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return;

    // Search for which small bucket the number is. Similar as before,
    // If b = 4, h_ = 3, there will be C[3][3] numbers
    // If b = 4, h_ = 4, there will be C[3][4] numbers
    // If b = 4, h_ = 5, there will be C[3][5] numbers
    // ...
    // If b = 4, h_ = h, there will be C[3][h] numbers
    //
    // Also, it's very easy to prove that:
    // C[3][3]                                    = C[4][4]
    // C[3][3] + C[3][4]                          = C[4][5]
    // C[3][3] + C[3][4] + C[3][5]                = C[4][6]
    // ...
    // C[3][3] + C[3][4] + C[3][5] + .. + C[3][h] = C[4][h+1]
    //
    // Now let's determine which C[b][i], where i is [b..(h+1)]
    unsigned* lb = lower_bound(&C[b][b], &C[b][h+1]+1, n);
    int c = lb-(&C[b][b])+b;

    // Don't forget to decrease c to get the index of the highest bit 1
    --c;

    // Fill the actual highest bit
    bs.set(c);

    // When c < b, lb must point to C[b][b] == 1, which means all lower bits
    // are also 1's, and we should stop here
    if (c < b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < c; ++i)
            bs.set(i);
        return;
    }

    // Deduct the number of numbers in the lower buckets, and search for
    // (b-1) 1's in a smaller bucket. Apparently, the possible highest 1
    // should be at index c-1, since the current bucket's highet 1 is at
    // index c
    FillBitset(n-C[b][c], b-1, c-1, bs);
}

inline unsigned GetNumber(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    // From index to position
    ++n;

    // Get which bucket Number[n] is
    unsigned* lb = lower_bound(S, S+N, n);
    int b = lb-S; // There are b 1's in the number, and b is always > 0
                  // because n == 0 is excluded above

    // So let's go to the core algorithm: get the position in the bucket
    // For each bucet, we need to divide it into small bags/buckets.
    // 
    // If b = 4, there will be [3..30] = 28 bags to represent how many numbers
    // whose highest one is at index 3, 4, 5, .. 30
    // 
    // If b = 4, and the highest 1 is at index 3, there will be C[3][3] numbers
    // If b = 4, and the highest 1 is at index 4, there will be C[3][4] numbers
    // If b = 4, and the highest 1 is at index 5, there will be C[3][5] numbers
    // ...
    // If b = 4, and the highest 1 is at index 30, there will be C[3][30] numbers
    //
    // Now our task is to find which small bucket the number is
    bitset<N> bs;
    FillBitset(n-S[b-1], b, N-2, bs);

    return (unsigned)bs.to_ulong();
}
```

Test Input:

```
0
1
2
31
32
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
496
497
498
2147483647
1234567890
987654321
6123512
852412
123125
67658153
214155
5623674
```

Test Output:

```
0
1
2
1073741824
3
0
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
2048
4096
8192
16384
32768
65536
131072
262144
524288
1048576
2097152
4194304
8388608
16777216
33554432
67108864
134217728
268435456
536870912
1073741824
3
5
1610612736
7
11
2147483647
1195924317
1467508257
147227152
1099186184
135856144
1247429124
57624
100730919
```